# How do i print each line here in a for loop

Tags: python-2.7

```
 thanks for the follow :)
hii... if u want to make a new friend just add me on facebook! :) xx 
Just wanna say if you ever feel lonely or sad or bored, just come and talk to me. I'm    free anytime :)
I hope she not a spy for someone. I hope she real on neautral side. Because just her who   i trust. :-)
  not always but sometimes maybe :)
\u201c Funny how you get what you want and pray for when you want the same thing God   wants.  :)  
 Thank you :) can you follow me on Twitter so I can DM you?
RT   dj got us a fallin in love and yeah earth number one m\u00fcsic listen thank you    king :-)
 found a cheeky weekend for \u00a380 return that's flights + hotel.. middle of april, im    still looking pal :)
RT   happy birthday mary ! Hope you have a good day :)
Thank god twitters not blocked on the school computers cause all my data is gone on my  phone :(
 enjoy tmrro. saw them earlier this wk here in tokyo :)
```

**UPDATE:**

Oki, maybe my question was wrong. I have to do this:

1. Open file and read from it
2. Remove some links, names and stuff from it (I have used regex, but don't know if it the right way to do
3. After i got clean code (only tweets with sad face or happy face) i have to print each line out, cause i have to loop each like this:

   for line in tweets:
           if '' in line:
               cl.train(line,'happy')
          else if '' in line:
               cl.train(line,'sad')

My code so far you see  here, but it doesn't work yet.

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

tweets = []


tweets = open('englishtweet.txt').read()


regex_username = '@[^\s]*' # regex to detect username in file
regex_url = 'http[^\s]*' # regex to detect url in file
regex_names = '#[^\s]*' # regex to detect # in file

for username in re.findall(regex_username, tweets):
    tweets = tweets.replace(username, '')

for url in re.findall(regex_url, tweets):
    tweets = tweets.replace(url, '')

for names in re.findall(regex_names, tweets):
    tweets = tweets.replace(names, '')
```

Comment: While the answers to you question are definitely below, in general, I would recommend looking at the [file documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), since they tell you exactly how to do this in their examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the first line, use `next`

```
with open("englishtweet.txt","r") as infile:
    print next(infile).strip()
    # this prints the first line only, and consumes the first value from the
    # generator so this:
    for line in infile:
        print line.strip()
    # will print every line BUT the first (since the first has been consumed)
```

I'm also using a context manager here, which will automatically close the file once you exit the `with` block instead of having to remember to call `tweets.close()`, and also will handle in case of error (depending on what else you're doing in your file, you may throw a handled exception that doesn't allow you to get to the `.close` statement).

If your file is very small, you could use `.readlines`:

```
with open("englishtweet.txt","r") as infile:
    tweets = infile.readlines()
# tweets is now a list, each element is a separate line from the file
print tweets[0] # so element 0 is the first line
for line in tweets[1:]: # the rest of the lines:
    print line.strip()
```

However that's not really suggested to read a whole file object into memory, as with some files it can simply be a huge memory waster, especially if you only need the first line -- no reason to read the whole thing to memory.

That said, since it looks like you may be using these for more than just one iteration, maybe `readlines` *IS* the best approach

Comment: If you add the `for`-loop case, upvote for you, otherwise you haven't fully answered the OP's question.

Comment: @aruisdante I missed that part, my mistake. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it. Just remove the .read() when you originally open the file. Then you can loop through the lines.

```
tweets = open('englishtweet.txt','r')
for line in tweets:
    print line
tweets.close()
```

Comment: This will print every line and not close the file.

Comment: Indeed. The fix is to simply change the first line to `with open(...) as tweets:` and indent the other lines appropriately.

Comment: True, so that doesn't meet the first requirement. But it would meet the second requirement, to print each line one by one, unless I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I edited to close the file, although I agree that Adam's answer is better. I would upvote, but I just joined :)